# UIPasteBoard string never get a right value after cut a text

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, uitextview, cut, uipasteboard

i have cut a text in a textview using UIMenuController and i want to paste it in another place. But the UIPasteBoard string never get a right value. FYI, it just happen in cut process, but it's no problem in copy.

In example : 
i have copied "XYZ" and paste it, the UIPasteBoard string is contain the right value, there is "XYZ"

then, i want to cut "ABC" and paste it, but the UIPasteBoard string contain the wrong value, it stil "XYZ" not "ABC", and the xcode output give me a text `Webcore NSBeep()!`

I dont understand why it can happen, can somebody give me some clue? thank you

**UPDATE**

i just use canPerformAction method :

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender{

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to cut and paste and any code between those transactions (that are relevant to this question).

Comment: @WrightsCS i have update my question, did you know what Webcore NSBeep()! mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should be setting the pasteboard with simple text:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:@"XYZ"];
```

### Using your own `UIMenuController`:

```
UIMenuItem * copy = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy Text" action:@selector(copyText:)];

UIMenuController * actionMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[actionMenu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: copy, nil]];
[actionMenu setTargetRect:someButton.frame inView:someButton.superview];
[actionMenu setArrowDirection:UIMenuControllerArrowDefault];
[actionMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

-(void)copyText:(id)sender {
    UIButton * button = (UIButton*)sender;
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:button.titleLabel.text];
}
```

Comment: where will i have to put that?

Comment: no. I'm not sure what other code you have, the menu is called by you somehow. wether its an IBAction, or whatever.

Comment: so, i have to make a subclass of UIMenuController ?

Comment: i didnt call uimenucontroller in my code, the menucontroller appear after i select the text

Comment: if you are using the system menu copy / paste then iOS should handle all of that.

Comment: i have the same asumption, but then, i've got that problem

Comment: use my method then and create your own menu this way you can control what goes on your pasteboard and how its handled.

Answer (score -1):

> In example : i have copied "XYZ" and paste it, the UIPasteBoard string
>   is contain the right value, there is "XYZ"
>
> then, i want to cut "ABC" and paste it, but the UIPasteBoard string
>   contain the wrong value, it stil "XYZ" not "ABC", and the xcode output
>   give me a text **Webcore NSBeep()!**

Answer: **Webcore NSBeep()!** because the "ABC" is not copied into your clipboard and the error notified with a beep (IMHO which is not wise way of notifying errors by any platform, it would have been any visual indication)

And please note : NSBeep() is part of the ApplicationKit framework which doesn't exist on the iPhone.

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you tell me how to fix this problem?